# Spacy v3 - list of tags and dependencies can not be found

Tags: spacy, spacy-3

I tried to find the list of tags and dependencies for spacy v3, but I couldn't.

Does anyone know where the following lists can be found, but for v3?

- v2 tags: https://v2.spacy.io/api/annotation#pos-tagging
- v2 dependencies: https://v2.spacy.io/api/annotation#dependency-parsing

Answer (score 1):

It's on the individual model pages, under "Label Scheme". See the [English Model](https://spacy.io/models/en) for example.

[image: label scheme screenshot]

Comment: I saw this list, but I was wondering if there is a detailed list so that I don't have to use the explain method to get details about any new item.

Comment: No, there is no detailed list. You can check the glossary source if you want to get them all at once I guess.